# Why does the prefix “auf-” change the word “hören” (hearing) to mean stop?

Tags: verb, etymology, prefix

A friend of mine who’s learning German asked me this and I couldn’t explain it to her. Is it just an example of how a word changes over time?

Perhaps it used to me “hear me tell you to stop”, “hör auf [my command]”?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. What a nice first question! Feel free to take a [tour] of the site, and visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Comment: "auf" is not uncommon as a prefix that describes something stops: *aufgeben*, *auflassen*, *auffliegen*, *aufgehen*, ...

Comment: This is common in some languages. In English, it's sometimes impossible to tell the meaning of a phrasal verb. E.g. "to look forward to" has nothing to do with "looking".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Duden**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufhoeren) says *mittelhochdeutsch ūfhœren, eigentlich wohl = aufhorchend von etwas ablassen*

> to stop (making noise) and prick (up) one's ears

but that etymology has no safe origin. So, we don't know.